# Ignore style cascading in React Native

Tags: react-native

*Context:*

*I am using [ReactNavigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/) to implement the navigation on my React Native app. All my views so far have no styles defined for them, and look just fine if I access them directly, without any routing. When accessed through the library's `StackNavigator`, however, they get extremely distorted, to the point where all components collapse into one. I suspect this is happening due to the cascading of the navigator's styling.*

**Question:**

**Is there any way to disable style cascading for a particular component in ReactNative?**

Comment: can you eloborate your problem with example case ?

Comment: The whole code is ca. 200 lines long. My noobness in ReactNative goes to the point where I don't know exactly which snippets could be relevant for this question. Could you give me some tips?

Comment: maybe you can push your project in github, and give some clue on your project.. i think it is ok.